# MongoDB $substract a date with a duration and take into account DST changes for a given timezone

Tags: mongodb, time, aggregation-framework, mongoid, dst

We have a specific need where we need to perform aggregation on time fields taking into account a specific "margin" and handling crossing the DST boundaries.

Suppose we have a project that starts at time `starts_at` and ends at time `ends_at` we actually want to glob all events that were created from `starts_at - safety_margin` to `ends_at`

So we have documents that look like this

`project: { "starts_at": "2019-04-01T10:28:05.711Z", "ends_at": "2019-01-29T10:28:05.711Z" }`

And the `safety_margin` is for now a constant of 1.weeks (translated into milliseconds in our MongoDB aggregation)

In our aggregation, we have the following stage

```
{ '$project': {
  safety_margin_starts_at: {
    '$subtract': ['$starts_at', safety_margin_duration]
  },
}
```

This will totally fails with DST with the given context :

- France Timezone (offset of +2 before April 1st, becomes +1 after April first)
- A project that starts at after the 1st or April (so offset of +1 in FR) and with the safety margin it becomes the 25th of March (offset of +2)

in our specs this will produce the error

```
project.starts_at               # => Mon, 01 Apr 2019 15:35:52 CEST +02:00
project.safety_margin_starts_at # => Mon, 25 Mar 2019 15:35:52 CET +01:00
# [Running our test]

expected 2019-03-25 13:35:52.357000000 +0000 to be within 0.1 of 2019-03-25 15:35:52 +0100
# The first figure is the one returned from the aggregation
```

Our app code actually makes a smart substraction where `starts_at - safety_margin_duration` becomes the same day/same hour regardless of DST changes when substracting days. It it possible to reproduce this behavior in MongoDB ?
Do you have some tips on how to tackle those issues ?

Maybe this could be a solution, but I've heard of a new way to manipulate times in aggregation, could this solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for handling dates with time zones is to perform all math in UTC. This means:

- If user input is in local time, convert dates/times to UTC before storing.
- Perform all operations on UTC times.
- When rendering/presenting dates/times to the user, convert to whichever time zone is appropriate at the time (the user viewing the time or the time zone in which the time was originally entered).

There is also a difference between the following two operations on local (non-UTC) times:

- Add 24 hours to a time
- Add 1 day to a time (time could change by 23, 24 or 25 hours depending on whether a DST boundary is crossed)

The application needs to be clear which of the two behaviors it wants where.

Given the code provided in the question, if `starts_at` and `safety_margin_starts_at` are model fields, they should store the times in UTC.

Mongoid documentation has additional guidance regarding time zones here: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#time-zones

Answer (score 0):

The example document has dates in UTC which has no DST and is safe to subtract millis as you did. 
I guess it's something in your code that causes the error.

> expected 2019-03-25 13:35:52.357000000 +0000 to be within 0.1 of 2019-03-25 15:35:52 +0100

has 2 hours difference between 13:35 and 15:35 which doesn't look right.

This is how you get french time in aggregation:

```
{ '$project': {
  safety_margin_starts_at: {
    '$subtract': ['$starts_at', safety_margin_duration]
  },
},
{ '$addFields': {
        safety_margin_starts_at_fr: { $dateToString: {
            date: "$d",
            format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z",
            timezone: "Europe/Paris"
        } }    
} }
```